# regular expression no more than one digit

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, regex-negation

how to make a regular expression into one number (only numbers) and that it does not exceed 10 from 0 to 10

```
/^[1-9][1]*$/.test(message)
```

It doesn't work that way for me.

Comment: `does not exceed 10` ... Is `10.000` a valid match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the amount of a specific character use `{}` instead of `[]`, in this case, as it is only one digit, you do not need to specify a count as 1 is default:

```js
/^[0-9]$/.test(message)
```

I assume you mean you want to match a single digit between 0 and 10. If not please comment to clarify.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need the incoming number not to exceed 10, i.e. a maximum of 9 :)

Comment: So anything between 0 and 9 inclusive? If so this should work.

Comment: Yes, whatever it is, don't exceed 9

Comment: In that case, this solution should work, give it a try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want *integers* or whole numbers, then use:

```
/^(?:[0-9]|10)$/
```

If you want to allow for decimals, then use:

```
/^(?:[0-9](?:\.\d+)?|10(?:\.0+)?)$/
```

The second regex says to match:

- `^` from the start of the number
- `(?:`

  - `[0-9]` 0 to 9
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` any optional decimal component
  - `|` OR
  - `10` match integer 10
  - `(?:\.0+)?` optional zero decimal only
- `)`
- `$` end of the number

Comment: Hi Tim,please add some explanation as well, so others can also understand the post.